# React + Django (session) authentication

Tags: authentication, react.js, django, jsx

Is authentication implemented correctly?

At the entry point to the app, which is `App.js`, query the Django server, which responds whether the current user is authenticated after checking `request.user.isAuthenticated`

I am not using `redux`, just storing authentication state in a local object (this can't be tampered with I assume?). This is reset on signout and I guess it is also lost and re-queried whenever the app is reloaded.

All app routes except the login route are behind `PrivateRoute`, which will redirect to login unless `myAuth.isAuthenticated === true`.

Any additional comments welcome.

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MainContainer from "../containers/MainContainer";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import store from "../store";
import BrowserRouter from "react-router-dom/es/BrowserRouter";
import {Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
import myAuth from "../myAuth";
import {APP_LOGIN_PATH} from "../constants/paths";


class App extends Component {
    state = {
        loaded: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        myAuth.authenticate(() => this.setState({
            loaded: true,
        }))
    }

    render() {
        const { loaded } = this.state;
        return (
            loaded ? (
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path={ APP_LOGIN_PATH } component={ LoginPage } />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/app" component={ MainContainer } />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            ) : (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            )
        )
    }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        myAuth.isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: APP_LOGIN_PATH, state: { from: props.location }}} />
    )} />
);

const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");

wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , wrapper) : null;
```

myAuth.js

```
const myAuth = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isStaff: false,
    isSuperuser: false,

    authenticate(cb) {
        console.log("authenticate");
        fetch("/session_user/")
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong during authentication");
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.isAuthenticated = data.isAuthenticated;
                this.isStaff = data.isStaff;
                this.isSuperuser = data.isSuperuser;
            })
            .then(cb)
    },

    signout(cb) {
        fetch("/logout/")
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong while logging out");
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.isAuthenticated = false;
                this.isStaff = false;
                this.isSuperuser = false;
            })
    }
};

export default myAuth;
```

Answer (score -3):

The client-side data can definitely be tampered with so you should not rely on that for security.

Comment: Can you be more specific - which part of the code depends on client-side data, and what can be done to improve it?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could expand on this answer.